# How to Set Up A Dynamic Startdate And Enddate using Advanced Editor in PowerQuery

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, static, powerquery

I initially created an SQL code with a static `StartDate` and `EndDate` in `PowerQuery` (see code below).

**SQL Script with Static values:**

---

```
Select extract(month from STAGE_DATE) as Calendar_Month, count(id) as 
        number_of_int
from stage_table 
where type_code LIKE 'X%'
and stage_date >= to_date('01022021','ddmmyyyy')  ---StartDate
and stage_date <= to_date('30042021','ddmmyyyy')  ---EndDate
group by extract(month from STAGE_DATE)
```

---

However, I want the users to be able to change the StartDate and EndDate. After some research, there is a function called Advanced Editor that can be used. I created a table called Parameters (Insert--> Table):

```
Column 1: Parameter Column 2: Value
StartDate                  01022021
EndDate                    30042021
```

Then, I used "Advanced Editor" to define the Parameters Table. I started by naming StartDate as follow:

```
(ParameterName as text) =>
let
ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=
if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in
Value
```

Then I entered fnGetParameter('StartDate') in the initial SQL (see below), but I keep getting an error message saying: "DataSource.Error: Oracle: ORA-00904: "FNGETPARAMETER": invalid identifier"

```
Select extract(month from STAGE_DATE) as Calendar_Month, count(id) as 
        number_of_int
from stage_table 
where type_code LIKE 'X%'
and stage_date >= to_date(fnGetParameter('StartDate'),'ddmmyyyy') 
and stage_date <= to_date(fnGetParameter('EndDate'),'ddmmyyyy') 
group by extract(month from STAGE_DATE)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I9xb.png)

Thank you in advance for looking into this!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Ken Puls' fnGetParameter() function

you can also see [excel-power-query-using-sql-to-pass-row-value-as-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68713706/excel-power-query-using-sql-to-pass-row-value-as-parameter)

```
//Written by Ken Puls, FCPA, FCMA, MS MVP (Excel)
//Original Source: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

(ParameterName as text) =>
let ParamSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Parameters"]}[Content],
ParamRow = Table.SelectRows(ParamSource, each ([Parameter] = ParameterName)),
Value=if Table.IsEmpty(ParamRow)=true
then null
else Record.Field(ParamRow{0},"Value")
in Value
```

then replace StartDate with fnGetParameter("StartDate")

Comment: Thank you for this! I tried your code, but when replacing "01022021" by fnGetParameter("StartDate") in my first SQL. I get an error message saying that fnGetParameter: Invalid identifier (where Datasource = Oracle                                                                              Note: I named the Advanced Editor function = "StartDate"

Comment: You cant use fnGetParameter if you named the function StartDate   Maybe read the original article to see how its used at http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

Comment: I reviewed the excelguru.ca/blog and got stuck when creating fnGetParameter. I don't get the option 'Close and Load TO...'. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: I created the fnGetParamater using the code from Ken Puls website. I replaced my static starting date with fnGetParamater ("StartDate"), but I keep getting an error message: Oracle:ORA-00904:"FNGETPARAMETER": Invalid Identifier. Below is the code: Select extract(month from STAGE_DATE) as Calendar_Month, count(id) as 
        number_of_int
from stage_table 
where type_code LIKE 'X%'
and stage_date >= to_date(fnGetParameter('Start Date'),'ddmmyyyy')  ---StartDate
and stage_date <= to_date('30042021','ddmmyyyy')  ---EndDate
group by extract(month from STAGE_DATE) ----Thanks! @horseyride

Comment: please edit your question to reflect current state of your code

Comment: where exactly are you entering the SQL? This part [[[ stage_date >= to_date(fnGetParameter('StartDate'),'ddmmyyyy')  ]]] does not look right. You are combining code to be sent externally with code to be interpreted by PQ

Comment: See picture in my initial question. Thank you!

Comment: are you literally including SQL code in the middle of your powerquery code, just by typing it right in there? The above code is pasted from home...advanced editor?

Comment: The code for the "fnGetParameter" is pasted in the Avanced Editor section, whereas the other code is in (Data --> Get Data --> from Database --> from Oracle Database. Put the name of the Server and then write the code in Advanced options --> SQL statement then click ok. @horseyride